# Finding the expected number of distinct intersections when four diagonals are randomly drawn in regular hexagon

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Four diagonals are randomly drawn in a regular hexagon. Find the expected number of distinct
> intersections of these segments in the interior of the hexagon.

I believe that the maximum number of distinct intersections is $3,$ and the least is $1.$ So it suffices to calculate the expected value of having $1$ intersection, $2$ intersections, and $3$ intersections, and then add them up. However, I'm not really sure how to do this. I've tried using casework for depending on how many intersections there are but it doesn't seem to be very nice. I'm trying to somehow use linearity of expectation, but I'm not really sure how. May I have some help? Thanks in advance.

To clarify, this problem is #23 on an AoPS mock, called OIMC. Here is the link to the discussion thread. artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h2886911

Comment: can the diagonals only be drawn from one vertex to another?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To clarify, this problem is #23 on an AoPS mock, called OIMC. Here is the link to the discussion thread. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h2886911

Comment: Using linearity of expectation, $E=P_{\text{center}}+12\times P_{\text{outer}}$ Can you calculate those probabilities?

Comment: I will attempt to. Here, $P_\text{center}$ means the center intersection of the hexagon and $P_\text{outer}$ means the non-center intersections, right? So your equation is essentially equivalent to saying the expected intersections is the expected value of getting a center intersection added to the expected value of getting an outer intersection?

Comment: The expected intersections is the sum of the expected values for each of the 13 intersections. The twelve outer intersections have the same expected value.

Comment: Side note: 4 intersections is possible.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ok thanks for the explanation. I'll try to calculate the probability of center intersection and outer intersections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Daniel Mathias

---

Each vertex in the regular hexagon may be diagonally connected with three of the other vertices.  Also, each diagonal is associated with two vertices.  Therefore, there are

$$\frac{6 \times 3}{2} ~~\text{distinct diagonals} \tag1 $$

that may be drawn.

Label the vertices, in clockwise order, $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6.$  The challenge is to find an elegant enumeration method that permits shortcuts.  The $9$ diagonals are listed below:

\begin{array}{| l | l | l |}
\hline                   
  \text{Assigned Variable} & \text{Specific Diagonals} 
& \text{Diagonal Type} \\
  \hline
D_1 & \overline{(P_1,P_3)} & \text{Side} \\ \hline 
D_2 & \overline{(P_1,P_4)} & \color{red}{\text{Main}} \\ \hline
D_3 & \overline{(P_1,P_5)} & \text{Side} \\ \hline
D_4 & \overline{(P_2,P_4)} & \text{Side} \\ \hline
D_5 & \overline{(P_2,P_5)} & \color{red}{\text{Main}} \\ \hline
D_6 & \overline{(P_2,P_6)} & \text{Side} \\ \hline
D_7 & \overline{(P_3,P_5)} & \text{Side} \\ \hline
D_8 & \overline{(P_3,P_6)} & \color{red}{\text{Main}} \\ \hline
D_9 & \overline{(P_4,P_6)} & \text{Side} \\ \hline 
\end{array}

So, approaching the problem combinatorically, the enumeration will be

$$\frac{N}{\binom{9}{4} = 126}, \tag1 $$

since there are $(126)$ ways of selecting the $(4)$ diagonals.  In (1) above, $(N)$ will be the sum of the number of intersection points, for all $(126)$ sets of $(4)$ diagonals.

Note that:

- Any two main diagonals will always intersect in the exact center of the hexagon.
- Of the $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} = 15$ possible side-side pairings, the only ones that will intersect will be the side-side pairing that do not share a vertex and are not parallel.  There are $6$ such side-side pairings that share a vertex, and $3$ such pairings that are parallel.  
  Therefore, on average, $~\displaystyle \frac{6}{15} = \frac{2}{5}~$ such pairings will intersect.
- Any two main diagonals will always intersect in the center of the hexagon.  Further, no side diagonal will pass through the center of the hexagon.  Also, the only time that intersections between two different pair of diagonals will fall on the same point is when both of the diagonals are main diagonals. 
  That is, all side-side intersections will always be distinct, and all side-main intersections will always be distinct.

I will break up the analysis into cases, depending on how many of the $(4)$ diagonals chosen are main diagonals.

For $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, I will use $T_k$ to represent how many intersection points are enumerated for Case $k$.

- Case 1: all three main diagonals are chosen. 
  There are $\displaystyle ~\binom{3}{3} \times \binom{6}{1} = 6~$ corresponding sets of $(4)$ diagonals. 
  In each such set, the three main diagonals will all intersect in the exact center of the hexagon, and each side diagonal will add exactly one additional intersection point. 
  Therefore, the final total for this case is 
  $T_1 = 6 \times [1 + 1] = 12.$
- Case 2: Two of the three main diagonals are chosen, and these two intersect in the hexagon center. 
  There are $\displaystyle ~\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} = 45~$ corresponding sets of $(4)$ diagonals. 
  By symmetry, you can assume without loss of generality, that the pertinent main diagonals are $D_2, D_5.$ 
  So, the $(15)$ pertinent cases are analyzed as follows: 
  There will be $(15)$ intersections of the two main diagonals. 
  $(2)$ of the $(6)$ side diagonals will not intersect with either main diagonal, and the other $(4)$ of the $(6)$ side diagonals will intersect with exactly $(1)$ of the main diagonals.
  This implies that on average, each side diagonal will intersection with $(2/3)$ of the main diagonals. 
  So, the corresponding $(15)$ side diagonal pairs will create  $\displaystyle ~\left[2 \times \frac{2}{3} \times 15\right] = 20~$ side-main intersections. 
  As discussed in the notes, there will be an additional $~(15 - [6 + 3] = 6)~$ side-side intersection points. 
  Therefore, the final total for this case is 
  $T_2 = 3 \times (15 + 20 + 6) = 123$ intersection points.

Incidentally, under the assumption that the $(2)$ main diagonals are $~D_2,D_5, ~$the added side pair of $~D_3,D_4~$ will have a total of $(1)$ intersection point, while the added side pair of $~D_7,D_9~$ will have a total of $\color{red}{(4) ~\text{intersection points}}.$

- Case 3: One of the three main diagonals is chosen. 
  There are $\displaystyle ~\binom{3}{1} \times \binom{6}{3} = 60~$ corresponding sets of $(4)$ diagonals. 
  Without loss of generality, it will be assumed that the main diagonal is $~D_2$. All of the analysis in Case 3 will merely represent a re-organization of the previous analysis. 
  So, the $(20)$ pertinent cases are analyzed as follows: 
  There are $(0)$ main-main intersections. 
  Only $(2)$ of the (6) side diagonals will intersect with a main diagonal. 
  So, on average, each side diagonal will intersect with $~\dfrac{1}{3}~$ of a main diagonal. 
  Therefore, in the $(20)$ pertinent cases, there will be 
  $\displaystyle \left[20 \times \binom{3}{1} \times \frac{1}{3} = 20\right]~$ side-main intersections. 
  As previously noted, $~\displaystyle \frac{2}{5}~$ of all possible side-side pairings will intersect. 
  Therefore, in the $(20)$ pertinent cases, there will be 
  $\displaystyle \left[20 \times \binom{3}{2} \times  \frac{2}{5} = 24\right]~$ side-side intersections. 
  Therefore, the final total for this case is 
  $T_3 = 3 \times (0 + 20 + 24) = 132$ intersection points.
- Case 4: None of the three main diagonals is chosen. 
  There are $\displaystyle ~\binom{3}{0} \times \binom{6}{4} = 15~$ corresponding sets of $(4)$ diagonals. 
  All of the analysis in Case 4 will merely represent a re-organization of the previous analysis. 
  So, the $(15)$ pertinent cases are analyzed as follows: 
  There are $(0)$ main-main intersections. 
  There are $(0)$ side-main intersections. 
  As previously discussed, of the $~\displaystyle 15 \times \binom{4}{2} = 90~$ side-side pairings, only $~\dfrac{2}{5}~$ of these will result in an intersection. 
  Therefore, the final total for this case is 
  $T_4 = 90 \times \dfrac{2}{5} = 36$ intersection points.

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4 = 12 + 123 + 132 + 36 = 303.$$

Therefore, the expected number of intersection points is

$$\frac{303}{126}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Response to the comment of Daniel Mathias.

> Linearity of expectation gives the same result without all the casework. See my comment above.

My response: $\color{red}{\text{Wow!}}$ 
I just confirmed his comment. 
Using the vertex labeling at the start of my answer, and using the syntax $[(a,b)::(c,d)]$ to denote the intersection point of $\overline{(P_a,P_b)}$ and $\overline{(P_c,P_d)},$ you have the following intersection points:

- $[(1,3)::(2,4)], [(1,3)::(2,5)], [(1,3)::(2,6)], [(1,4)::(2,6)], [(1,4)::(3,5)], [(1,5)::(2,6)], [(1,5)::(3,6)], [(1,5)::(4,6)], [(2,4)::(3,5)], [(2,4)::(3,6)], [(2,5)::(4,6)], [(3,5)::(4,6)].$
- $[(1,4)::(2,5)]$.

In the first bullet point above, the $(12)$ *outer* intersection points will each occur $~\displaystyle\binom{9-2}{4-2} = \binom{7}{2} = 21~$ times in the $~\displaystyle\binom{9}{4} = 126~$ total ways of choosing $(4)$ of the diagonals at random.

For the second bullet point above, the internal intersection point can occur in $(2)$ different ways:

- A set of $(4)$ diagonals that contain exactly $(2)$ main diagonals: 
  Enumeration is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} = 45.$
- A set of $(4)$ diagonals that contain exactly $(3)$ main diagonals: 
  Enumeration is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{6}{1} = 6.$
- So, the total number of ways that the inner intersection point will occur is $(45 + 6 = 51).$

Therefore, using the approach of Daniel Mathias, in the fraction :

$$\frac{N}{126},$$

the value of $N$ may be computed as

$$(12 \times 21) + (51) = 303.$$

Comment: Linearity of expectation gives the same result without all the casework. See my comment above.

Comment: @DanielMathias : +1 : Wow!  I need some time to verify your analysis.  Then, I will update my answer with an Addendum.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @DanielMathias Addendum added to respond to your comment.

Comment: @mathisfun See also the Addendum to my answer.